# How to save / load this data

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a Map that is a `TGraphicControl` with the properties

```
HexRow : Integer;
HexColumns : integer;
TempMap :TBitmap;
```

I would like to save all this data into one file. And when I read in the file I can get all this data. Like so...

```
Procedure Map.Load(name :String);
begin
  Something.LoadfromFile(string);
  TempMap := Something.Bitmap;
  HexRow  := Something.hexRow;
  HexColumn := Something.HexColumn;
end;
```

but no idea what "something" is.  Also same for saving it should save all these propertys

Comment: Have a look at the source of some classes you know that can load/save data to a file (f.i. `TStringList`)

Comment: I know bitmap can, but can you save values to a bitmap..i guess kind of like meta data? I know some images now store the location the image was taken, but no idea how to do that

Comment: Just have a look at some and learn from the source

Comment: I would personally use database here. SQLite could be a good choice. You'd have those metadata stored neatly in record fields with an image in blob stream. You could even search images by those metadata (if that is needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write methods that write and read the information. You could do it using binary writer and reader objects.

```
procedure TMap.SaveToStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  Writer: TBinaryWriter;
begin
  Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create(Stream);
  try
    Writer.Write(HexRow);
    Writer.Write(HexColumn);
    Bitmap.SaveToStream(Stream);
  finally
    Writer.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMap.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  Reader: TBinaryReader;
begin
  Reader := TBinaryReader.Create(Stream);
  try
    HexRow := Reader.ReadInteger;
    HexColumn := Reader.ReadInteger;
    Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Reader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or if you wanted to be cute then you could write the bitmap first, and stuff the extra information at the end of the file. I think then that most bitmap reading code would just ignore the extra numbers you stored at the end. Of course, those values would not survive a round trip using any software other than your own.

To save to and load from a file use `TFileStream`.

Of course, such a file format doesn't give you much room for future enhancement and modification. Personally I think I'd be inclined to use PNG format. This gives you compression and I believe that you can add custom metadata.

Comment: First sorry about last question, I am tired and confused.. Second, never used TStream, but I assume somewhere in there i would have to tell it where to stream too aka "somelocation.dat"  ?

Comment: Yes. Use `TFileStream` for files.

Comment: @GlenMorse Source of `TStrings.LoadFromFile` gives a perfect example